# Makefile Rule calls Rule - how to parse Variables at execution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to call another Rule that I have created to be used to serve multiple targets in my Makefile to create AWS Cloudformation Stacks.
The Rule looks like this:

```
aws/create_stack:
   aws cloudformation create-stack \
   --stack-name $(stack_name) \
   --region $(region) \
   --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```

I want to call the rule from another rule and define Variables for the rule at execution time like this:

```
aws/parameters: aws/create_stack
    $(MAKE) aws/create_stack stack_name=parameter region=$(REGION)
```

But for some reason when I execute the Makefile the Variables set in the receipe of the Caller Rule are not used by the first Rule I'm calling.

when I set the Variable separately outside of the Rule (aws/parameters) - it works.
How do I have to re-write it to keep the Variable assignment in the Rule (aws/parameter)?

Thank you A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Beta wrote you can use the "dependency approach"; a more condensed version looks like this:

```
aws/parameters: stack_name := parameter
aws/parameters: region := $(REGION)
was/parameters: aws/create_stack
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use recursion (`$(MAKE) ...`) here. Just use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
parameters: stack_name := parameter
parameters: region := $(REGION)
parameters: create_stack
    @echo parameters done

create_stack:
    @echo create_stack: stack_name is $(stack_name)
    @echo create_stack: region is $(region)
```